# How to increase the font size for the first letter of the header content in css

Tags: html, css

Hi I have the below header content name as "DISPLAYNAME". I want to increase the font size of first letter to 200%.

[image]

I tried as below css styling but it doesn't worked.

```
.header h1::before:first-letter{
font-size: 200%;
}
```

I am trying to find the solution and learn in the process.

Comment: why you use pseudo-element before? just use h1 .....

Comment: if you put the text into the `<h1>` itself, you can use `h1::first-letter`

Answer (score -1):

You will need to wrap `D` in span and give it a different style. Your HTML will be `<h1><span>D</span>isplayname</h1>`

then you can give span and h1 different stylings

Comment: The `D` is part of the `content` property of the `::before` pseudo-class. It can't be wrapped in another element.

Comment: why use `::before`? my suggestion is to get rid of that pseudo element and just put it in HTML `span`